# Is there a list of all stock messaging apps package names for all Android phone constructors?

Tags: android, sms, messaging

Alternatvely, is there an easy way to know the package name of a system app ?

Answer (score 5):

I just was Developing an App locker that have a category for important app to offer user to lock them.
and obviously default SMS app is important app to lock.
so i create my own list of default sms apps package name.
I hope this will be helpful for you and others help me to improve this list:

```
"com.google.android.apps.messaging"
"com.jb.gosms"
"com.concentriclivers.mms.com.android.mms"
"fr.slvn.mms"
"com.android.mms"
"com.sonyericsson.conversations"
"com.samsung.android.messaging"
```

Comment: That is great.Did you find other packageNames of messaging apps?

Answer (score 0):

What are you exactly trying to do? 
Alternatively, why do you need such a list ?

As a general advice, you shouldn't code anything according to a static list, because anything related to this list is likely to evolve.

Comment: I need the packages of all the messaging apps so I can handle their notifications in the status bar, there is no way to do this other than keeping the packages in a static list. All the information I get while getting the notification info is the package.

Comment: What about listening to the SMS broadcast ?

Comment: The point of the app is to be able to listen to any app by reading the status bar notifications and processing it the same way, I can't use SMS broadcast, users must be able to listen to GO Sms, Handsent SMS or both

Answer (score 0):

ya you can get

```
public class ListofAppinMyDevice {
    public class PInfo {   
        public String appname = "";   
        public String pname = "";   
        public String versionName = "";   
        public int versionCode = 0;   
    }   

    public ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) 
    {   
    ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        

    List<PackageInfo> packs = AppUtils.mContext.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);   
    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {   
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);

        ApplicationInfo s=p.applicationInfo;

        if(((s.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)!=1))
        {

        PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();

        newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(AppUtils.mContext.getPackageManager()).toString();   
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;   
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;   
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;   
         System.out.println("3rd party apps-------------------"+p.packageName +"--------"+newInfo.appname);
        res.add(newInfo);  
        }

        if ((!getSysPackages) ) {   
            continue ;   
        }   

    }   
    return res;    
}
```

}

//you can get the system installed app by using this below method

```
  public static void listPackages() {   
            ListofAppinMyDevice getmyApp=new ListofAppinMyDevice();

            apps =getmyApp.getInstalledApps(true); 
/* false = will get 3rd part package detials 
true -will get all system packages */  
            System.out.println("Total InstalledApps in your device--=="+apps.size());
            final int max = apps.size();   
            applist=new StringBuilder();
            for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {   
                String packageName=apps.get(i).pname;


    }
```

Comment: I'm looking for a user-friendly way to get the package name of an app, to ask my users to get it if I can't manage to get a list of all stock sms apps packages.

Comment: K this is alternate way to get the system app package name.