# How to retrieve information about running application in android?

Tags: android, android-ndk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can get how many apps installed in my device and there names or last accessed information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655477/how-can-get-how-many-apps-installed-in-my-device-and-there-names-or-last-accesse)

I want to retrieve the following information related to running application in android.
1.Running application Name
2.Data files related to particular application(files in assets/res folder whatever it is)
and any possible information related to application second point is most important i.e.data files related to particular application please help me to solve the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8655477/1012284

Answer (score 0):

You can retrive the running application's name from strings.xml(res/values/strings.xml) . [This link](http://mgmblog.com/2008/12/12/listing-androids-drawable-resources/) can help you to get all the name of images in drawable folder.